# encoding symbol in exported excel sheet in a gridview asp,net

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, webforms, export-to-excel

I'm working on a legacy system that has export to excel function from database to excel sheet.
the problem was that empty cells was showing symbols and i fixed it . Now the other problem , inside a single cell i found encoding symbols and i tried a lot of solutions and it still there .
[image: Data sample from exported excel]

My code :

```
 else if (ddl_excel_type.SelectedValue == "1")
            {
                GridView1.PagerSettings.Visible = false;

                //To Export all pages
                GridView1.AllowPaging = false;

                GridView1.DataBind();

               // GridView1.HeaderRow.BackColor = Color.White;

                DataTable dt = new DataTable("GridView_Data");
                //DataTable dtDetails = new DataTable("GridView_Details_Data");

                this.GetAllRisks();
                foreach (TableCell cell in GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells)
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(cell.Text);
                   // cell.BackColor = GridView1.HeaderStyle.BackColor;
                }

                GridView GridView2 = (GridView)GridView1.Rows[0].FindControl("GridView2");


                GridView2.PagerSettings.Visible = false;

                //To Export all pages
                GridView2.AllowPaging = false;

                GridView2.DataBind();
                //controls
                if (GridView2.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (TableCell cell in GridView2.HeaderRow.Cells)
                    {
                        dt.Columns.Add(cell.Text);
                       // cell.BackColor = GridView1.HeaderStyle.BackColor;

                    }

                }
                dt.Columns.RemoveAt(0);

                foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
                {

                    GridView gvOrderscell = (row.FindControl("GridView2") as GridView);



                    if (GridView2.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {


                        for (int j = 0; j < gvOrderscell.Rows.Count; j++)
                        {

                            dt.Rows.Add(row.Cells[1].Text, row.Cells[2].Text, row.Cells[3].Text, row.Cells[4].Text, row.Cells[5].Text, row.Cells[6].Text,
                                     row.Cells[7].Text, row.Cells[8].Text, row.Cells[9].Text, row.Cells[10].Text, row.Cells[11].Text, row.Cells[12].Text,
                                     row.Cells[13].Text, row.Cells[14].Text, row.Cells[15].Text, row.Cells[16].Text, row.Cells[17].Text, row.Cells[18].Text,
                                     row.Cells[19].Text, row.Cells[20].Text, row.Cells[21].Text, row.Cells[22].Text,
                     gvOrderscell.Rows[j].Cells[0].Text, gvOrderscell.Rows[j].Cells[1].Text, gvOrderscell.Rows[j].Cells[2].Text, gvOrderscell.Rows[j].Cells[3].Text, gvOrderscell.Rows[j].Cells[4].Text

                     );
//This is what i added for the symbols inside the cells but it didn't work
                            string textWithNewLine = row.Cells[j].Text.Replace("&#x0D", Environment.NewLine);

                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dt.Rows.Add(row.Cells[1].Text, row.Cells[2].Text, row.Cells[3].Text, row.Cells[4].Text, row.Cells[5].Text, row.Cells[6].Text,
                                      row.Cells[7].Text, row.Cells[8].Text, row.Cells[9].Text, row.Cells[10].Text, row.Cells[11].Text, row.Cells[12].Text,
                                      row.Cells[13].Text, row.Cells[14].Text, row.Cells[15].Text, row.Cells[16].Text, row.Cells[17].Text, row.Cells[18].Text,
                                      row.Cells[19].Text, row.Cells[20].Text, row.Cells[21].Text, row.Cells[22].Text);

                    }


                }





                    Response.Clear();
                    Response.Charset = "";
                    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename= Risk and consquences.xls");

                    //Here we set the correct encoding so that all characters show!
                    Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                    Response.Charset = "65001";
                    byte[] b = new byte[] {
                        0xef,
                        0xbb,
                        0xbf
                    };
                    Response.BinaryWrite(b);

                    System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
                    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
                    System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid dg = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid();
                    dg.DataSource = dt;
                    dg.DataBind();
                    dg.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
                    Response.Write(Convert.ToString( stringWrite));
                 //This is what i added for the symbols inside the cells removal and didn't work
                    stringWrite.Write("br {mso-data-placement:same-cell;}");
                    Response.Write(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Convert.ToString(stringWrite)));

                    Response.End();

            }
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write the string back to the Cell:

```
//This is what i added for the symbols inside the cells but it didn't work
string textWithNewLine = row.Cells[j].Text.Replace("&#x0D", Environment.NewLine);
row.Cells[j].Formula = textWithNewLine;
```

Comment: Hi Geoff , `FormulaR1C1` extension is causing error line under it ,Is there a library for it ?

Comment: I replaced with extension `.Text` but the excel still the same.

Comment: It may be **.Formula** extension.  Which version of Excel are you using?